# How to Redirect the Root with data in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

How to Send the Data when Redirect the URL.

Code in Controller:

```
return Redirect::to('cuslist')->with('asdasdadsads', '$values');
```

Comment: your redirected route might be returning a view? pass these values over there `view('someview')->with(your data)`

Comment: Controller `return view('cuslist')->withData($values);` and within your view `print_r($data);`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to redirect to an action in controller,

```
return Redirect::action('UserController@profile', array('user' => 1));
```

Comment: I need to Send Database Values to View, How can I Send Values on Redirect

Answer (score 1):

The way you are redirecting with data is correct.

`with` method flashes the data into session.

So to access the data you flashed within the view use the `Session::get` method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
return view('your_view_neme')->with(['first_index'=>$first_value,'second_index'=>$second_value]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can use the following syntax(using named parameters):

***Redirect to route***

```
return Redirect::to('cuslist', array('id' => $id, 'age' => $age));
```

***Redirect to named route***

```
return Redirect::route('cuslist', array('id' => $id, 'age' => $age));
```

***Redirect to controller method***

```
return Redirect::action('YourController@yourMethod', array('id' => $id, 'age' => $age));
```

More information can be found at : https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/responses#redirects